# How to create a time series analysis where y-axis are categorical variable?

Tags: r, time-series, categorical-data

I'm trying to create a time series that will reflect an activity pattern for an animal over a 24 hour period. There are 5 mutually exclusive activities that an animal could be doing, coded as w, r, s, a, and o, and a duration for each in seconds over a total time of 600 seconds.

```
Top row:  
State   duration


w   00:07:43
out 00:03:18
w   00:05:05
r   00:00:23
w   00:07:40
r   00:05:33
w   00:02:26
r   00:03:39
w   00:29:15
r   00:02:48
w   00:01:21
r   00:12:03
w   00:03:03
r   00:02:12
w   00:00:22
r   00:01:22
w   00:01:49
r   00:00:15
r   00:00:17
w   00:05:08
r   00:02:50
w   00:01:31
r   00:02:17
w   00:04:32
r   00:03:43
w   00:01:09
r   00:00:38
w   00:03:29
r   00:00:52
w   00:04:29
r   00:08:04
w   00:01:20
r   00:02:42
w   00:00:36
r   00:01:21
w   00:02:45
r   00:00:34
w   00:01:11
r   00:07:05
w   00:09:19
r   00:01:31
w   00:01:34
r   00:00:38
w   00:02:43
r   00:00:59
w   00:03:11
r   00:01:39
w   00:01:08
r   00:00:47
w   00:01:06
r   00:06:33
w   00:02:59
r   00:01:43
w   00:04:14
r   00:04:05
w   00:00:19
r   00:05:55
w   00:04:02
out 00:28:50
w   00:01:55
r   00:01:08
w   00:00:46
r   00:01:35
w   00:00:19
r   00:00:32
w   00:04:44
r   00:03:08
w   00:01:02
r   00:00:58
w   00:00:21
r   00:07:42
w   00:00:33
r   00:00:58
w   00:03:03
r   00:01:01
w   00:01:24
r   00:00:51
w   00:05:50
r   00:01:07
w   00:01:50
r   00:00:38
w   00:02:21
r   00:03:38
w   00:07:21
r   00:00:03
w   00:05:19
r   00:00:36
w   00:01:31
r   00:00:38
w   00:00:28
r   00:02:32
w   00:00:45
r   00:13:02
w   00:01:49
r   00:09:09
w   00:02:02
r   00:01:03
w   00:03:26
r   00:03:49
w   00:04:48
r   00:02:13
w   00:02:10
r   00:01:23
w   00:00:40
r   00:12:39
w   00:04:25
r   00:00:41
w   00:00:57
r   00:00:33
w   00:00:50
r   00:01:10
w   00:01:04
r   00:00:14
w   00:02:41
r   00:01:22
w   00:00:13
r   00:04:27
w   00:03:21
r   00:04:36
w   00:00:37
r   00:01:49
w   00:01:20
r   00:02:35
r   00:00:08
r   00:00:34
w   00:00:18
r   00:06:44
w   00:04:08
r   00:03:27
w   00:01:16
r   00:00:21
w   00:12:00
r   00:00:20
w   00:09:58
r   00:00:04
w   00:05:40
r   00:02:52
w   00:02:16
r   00:00:19
w   00:03:27
r   00:00:46
w   00:01:55
r   00:00:28
w   00:00:22
r   00:03:53
w   00:23:50
r   00:01:24
w   00:03:01
r   00:01:23
w   00:00:18
r   00:00:42
w   00:01:02
r   00:09:41
w   00:01:19
r   00:08:29
w   00:02:20
r   00:00:10
w   00:03:12
r   00:00:11
w   00:02:00
r   00:07:02
w   00:04:46
out 00:04:06
w   00:01:52
r   00:00:24
w   00:00:32
r   00:03:34
w   00:00:55
r   00:05:41
w   00:00:26
r   00:01:39
w   00:00:30
r   00:00:25
r   00:00:30
w   00:01:36
r   00:05:15
r   00:02:12
w   00:00:19
r   00:03:57
w   00:00:58
r   00:00:19
r   00:02:39
w   00:01:46
r   00:00:50
r   00:02:58
r   00:00:22
w   00:00:46
r   00:32:18
w   00:06:54
r   00:30:58
s   00:11:57
r   00:02:00
s   00:02:52
r   00:00:47
w   00:00:22
r   00:01:11
r   00:02:00
s   00:17:53
r   00:02:00
s   00:20:28
a   00:02:15
s   00:32:05
r   00:05:33
r   00:00:29
w   00:00:30
r   00:02:00
s   00:21:04
r   00:02:00
s   00:59:44
r   00:00:41
w   00:00:52
r   00:02:00
s   00:03:20
r   00:06:04
w   00:00:40
r   00:02:59
w   00:00:11
r   00:01:06
r   00:01:34
w   00:00:21
r   00:07:52
s   00:13:10
r   00:02:00
s   00:29:58
a   00:01:36
s   00:03:12
r   00:02:00
s   00:50:48
a   00:00:27
s   00:07:49
r   00:02:00
s   00:28:35
a   00:00:15
r   00:02:00
s   01:17:04
a   00:00:11
s   00:01:14
a   00:00:12
s   00:04:30
r   00:04:31
w   00:00:08
r   00:02:00
s   00:09:38
a   00:00:19
s   00:07:10
r   00:02:00
s   00:36:09
a   00:00:31
s   00:51:41
r   00:02:00
s   00:15:32
s   01:05:16
r   00:00:48
w   00:00:19
r   00:02:00
s   00:06:50
r   00:04:59
w   00:00:11
r   00:02:14
r   00:02:00
s   00:05:31
r   00:01:02
r   00:00:48
r   00:00:03
r   00:01:04
r   00:00:05
r   00:00:37
w   00:00:16
r   00:14:09
w   00:00:07
r   00:02:00
s   00:03:40
r   00:02:00
s   00:13:03
r   00:04:26
s   00:15:19
r   00:00:32
r   00:01:00
r   00:02:00
s   00:12:03
r   00:02:20
r   00:02:22
r   00:02:08
w   00:00:11
r   00:07:19
w   00:00:33
r   00:09:22
r   00:04:48
r   00:02:34
w   00:02:14
r   00:00:19
w   00:01:47
r   00:03:09
w   00:04:49
r   00:01:41
w   00:07:57
r   00:02:04
w   00:09:57
```

I would like to obtain something like this: http://meanjin.com.au/editions/volume-69-number-2-2010/article/on-the-invisibility-of-sleep/

The only way I can do it at the moment is to divide every dog into repetitive seconds, for examples 5 secs in r would be 1,1,1,1,1 for behaviour 1, which requires a vector of 600 seconds for each animal on each day.

Is there a better way of doing it? I have explored the ts() function in R but cannot find a way of plotting categorical variabes on the y axis and the duration of each on the x axis (without splitting the data as mentioned above). Most examples and tutorials of time series data available have continuous data on the y axis.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use xts:

```
library(xts)
```

Convert categorical to some numeric with a mapping:

```
value_map <- c( w = 1, out = 2, r = 3, s  = 4, a = 5)
values1 <- value_map[as.character(df1$State)]
```

Convert durations to time:

```
origin1 <- "2015-01-01"
duration2 <- as.POSIXct (sprintf("2015-01-01 %s", df1$duration)) - as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")
 time1 <- as.POSIXct( c(0, cumsum(as.numeric(duration2))), origin=origin1)
```

Create time series

```
ts1 <- xts( c(values1, tail(values1,1)),  time1)
```

Plot time series

```
plot(ts1, type="s")
```

Comment: Thanks for this. When I use this code, after the last line of code when I try to plot I get this message:
Error in if (on == "years") { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed 

Any idea what's not working? Thanks!

Comment: No idea. Can you share your data object or your final time series object? With `dput(ts1)` for example?

Comment: Sure- It's added in the main question. Thanks!

Comment: There are also *s* and *a*  states. Update `value_map <- c( w = 1, out = 2, r = 3, s  = 4, a = 5)`.

Comment: Hello, I've used the code with these updated -sorry, forgot to mention this earlier.